# iOS : dealloc & IBOutlet

Tags: ios, memory-management

Is it necessary to set all `@property`s with `retain` modifier declared as `IBOutlet` to `nil` inside the `- (void)dealloc` method? Will memory be consumed / wasted if I don't do so?

Assume that Automatic Reference Counting is turned OFF.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it required to set outlets varibles to nil in dealloc (even after IOS 3.0)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658535/is-it-required-to-set-outlets-varibles-to-nil-in-dealloc-even-after-ios-3-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to be "How do I handle a `retain` property in dealloc?" Well let's look at an example.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myView;
```

When your view is loaded `myView` is retained by two objects, your view hierarchy (by an internal `addSubview:` or similar) and your view controller (by means of the property setter method). A simple log is all that is needed to confirm this. placing this code in `viewDidLoad` will confirm this with an output of 2.

```
NSLog(@"myLabel is retained: %i", myView.retainCount);
```

There are two methods where you should address this pointer, and both are automatically filled in for you by `Xcode`.

First in `viewDidUnload` (Which is generally only called in low memory situations) you want to release the view, and since that will result in a dangling pointer you also want to set the pointer to nil. Xcode achieves this by simply using the setter method.

```
[self setMyView:nil];
```

The second place, and the place you asked about initially is `dealloc`. In dealloc you similarly need to release your property although in this case (Main thread only execution, based on the `IBOutlet` in the question) the dangling pointer should not be a problem. This seems reinforced by Xcode's automatic implementation of dealloc.

```
[myView release];
```

Of course setting the pointer to `nil` in addition to releasing would not be detrimental at all. And may even be preferable if this were not a main thread only `UIKit` element. But if you were worried about multi-threading you would likely just use `atomic` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Even without ARC it is not necessary to `nil` your `IBOutlets` in `-(void)dealloc`. Testing with Instruments shows that memory for the interface elements connected to `IBOutlets` is released just fine as soon as the `UIView` is deallocated.

However, if your app uses threading, it still might be a good practice to do so as it allows other threads to easily determine whether the object in question is still available.